# How to patch and verify if a Class was instantiated with a specific parameter?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In a nutshell this is the class I would like to test. To see if Tokenizer('english') was created with 'english'.

```
def summarize(news):
        language = 'english'
        parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(news.body, Tokenizer(language))
```

This is the test

```
    @mock.patch.object(PlaintextParser, 'from_string')
    @mock.patch('sumy.nlp.tokenizers.Tokenizer')
    def test_summarize_tokenizer_is_called_with_english(self, token_mock, parser_mock):
        news_mock = mock.MagicMock()
        body = u"xx"
        type(news_mock).body = mock.PropertyMock(return_value=body)
        Summarizer.summarize(news_mock)
        token_mock.assert_called_with('english')
```

I keep getting:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: Tokenizer('english')
Not called
```

But this should pass. What am I missing please?

Comment: Look closely at what you are mocking, and compare that to what you imported. `Tokenizer` is already bound to the `sumy.nlp.tokenizers.Tokenizer` class, so there is no point in patching the latter when you need to patch the global in the module-under-test. See [*Where to patch*](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky part of mocking.  Note that you're patching `Tokenizer` in the `sumy.nlp.tokenizers` namespace.  However, presumably you've got an import statement like:

```
from sumy.nlp.tokenizers import Tokenizer
```

in the module with `Summarizer`.  This puts the `Tokenizer` in the namespace of that module also.  Patching in the other (`sumy.nlp.tokenizers`) namespace doesn't effect the `Tokenizer` here.

---

One solution to this problem is to change your import statement in the module with `Summarizer`:

```
from sumy.nlp import tokenizers
```

then your function becomes:

```
def summarize(news):
    language = 'english'
    parser = PlaintextParser.from_string(news.body, tokenizers.Tokenizer(language))
```

Another solution that *could* work is to simply patch `Tokenizer` in the namespace of `Summarizer` (although, there are more subtleties here...)

Comment: First solution already works great. Many Thanks. +1